# I have uninstalled the 383 MB "gcc" and "brew doctor" does not complain. Homebrew no longer needs "gcc" in 2023? Is that correct?

Tags: command-line, homebrew, sonoma

I have uninstalled the 383 MB `gcc` and `brew doctor` does not complain. Homebrew no longer needs `gcc` in 2023?

I have looked at the [sizes of my homebrew packages](https://gist.github.com/eguven/23d8c9fc78856bd20f65f8bcf03e691b) and have therefore decided to uninstall `gcc`.

Homebrew does not need `gcc`? Is this correct in 2023? I remember that Homebrew used to want `gcc` as a dependency.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: AFAIK Homebrew requires Xcode (at least CLT), not gcc.

Comment: If you use brew, for sure you have Xcode CLT, so be careful, gcc is also part of Xcode. Try ```which gcc``` and ```gcc --version``` to see it. Also, the latest (external) gcc in osx are installed as ```gcc-13``` or ```gcc-11``` or whatever version you have.  Simply ```brew list``` to see what you have.

Comment: @Yoan Apple provides Clang in the CLT, not gcc.

Comment: `/usr/bin/gcc` just calls clang. It can't be removed in recent versions of macOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew relies on the Xcode Command Line Tools (which include `clang` as a compiler), not on its own `gcc` package. So unless you have other needs for `gcc`, it can be safely uninstalled.